# How do you distribute a list of integers to be as close to balanced as possible?

Tags: python, algorithm

How do you balance a set of items? By balance, each of the 4 variables should have no variance of more than +1 from any other variable.

Each number must remain whole, as they represent 1 physical item to be transferred.

```
Input a=1, b=2, c=3, d=10 
Output a=4, b=4, c=4, d=4
Ouput:
    Move 3 from d to a
    Move 2 from d to b
    Move 1 from d to c

Input a=1, b=2, c=0, d=0
Ouput a=1, b=1, c=1, d=0
Output:
    Move 1 from b to c

Input a=1, b=0, c=0, d=0
Output a=1, b=0, c=0, d=0
Output:
    Move None

Input a=0, b=1, c=0, d=1
Output a=0, b=1, c=0, d=1
Output:
    Move None
```

Comment: You haven't properly specified what "balance" means.

Comment: I've been thinking through this, and it seems like it would be a large set of nested if / elif statements comparing the totals, or taking the total of a + b + c + d, dividing by 4, and trying to distribute as closely to this as possible. It seems like it's a fundamental comp sci scenario, but I'm not familiar with what it would be called. Thus, I've created this question to gather ideas from more experienced folks.

Comment: The term *set* is slightly confusion in this context. The Python `set` type and the *mathematical set* on which it is based are inherently *unordered*.

Comment: I agree, was searching for a good word to use as it's a set in the idea that a, b, c, and d are unique, but unordered. Hence, I don't really know what a good term to use would be. List seems inappropriate as well. A set of variables was as close as I could convey the idea.

Comment: @KennyPowers Taking the mean certainly seems sensible, you just have to handle the cases where the mean is not a whole number, which is not particularly hard. I suggest you think about it yourself some more.

Comment: List would do fine as a description and as a representation of the data. Especially since you *want* to change it.

Comment: Would stay the same, as there's no variance greater than 1 for any variable.

Comment: Added your case as an input output example.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713631/distribute-items-in-buckets-equally-best-effort

Comment: And it's in a different language...

Comment: For the community, I don't get the down votes here. I've answered all possible vague portions to the question. I'm not asking for the answer to this problem. Just some pointers so I can learn. SO as a whole has gotten into this habit of doing a fly by on questions where someone is displeased, down votes and walks away.

Comment: @abccd: Looks like [english](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21718457/6419007) to me.

Comment: @Gassa programming language lol

Comment: @KennyPowers: I expect that the down votes are because your question doesn't show any particular attempt at a solution.  There's some work in the comments, but you haven't properly updated the posting.  You need to do that for this to be easily accessible for future Stack Overflow visitors -- which, after all, is that primary charter of this site.

Comment: @KennyPowers most people down vote because of the same reason as my first comment, what have you tried, you can ask questions here, but people here appreciate to see the things you already tried. It's good that you replied to the comment but it's better to edit the question since people usually read the question not the comments. And people who down voted usually wouldn't bother to come back to check on this.

Comment: @abccd So what? The first part of the problem is to arrive at an algorithm, which is not at all language-dependent. The question does not say "I have an idea but can't translate it into Python". It basically says "no idea at all". Most of the linked answers are also language agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a set of if/else statements.  Put your values into a list, not separate variables.  Take the mean, truncated to an integer.  Replicate that mean in another list of the same length.  You now have something like

```
vals = [1, 3, 4, 10]
mean = [4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Note that you have 2 items left over.  You need to distribute those.
In the mean list, add 1 to any element that's over the mean, until you run out of leftovers or elements.  You now have

```
vals = [1, 3, 4, 10]
mean = [4, 4, 4, 5]
```

In this case, you still have 1 left over.  Add it to any other element:

```
vals = [1, 3, 4, 10]
mean = [4, 5, 4, 5]
```

Now, it's tribial to compare the lists, one element at a time, and report the moves needed.  This gives you the minimal quantity of moved items to get the desired distribution.

Does that get you going?

---

**Response to OP comment**

First of all, your posting asked for the balance, not the series of transfers needed.  Next, I don't see where it *isn't* trivial.  Anything less than the "mean" array is a recipient; anything more is a donor.  You never have product moving more than once: just limit the transfer to the smaller of the amount available and the amount needed.

Consider a simple, but non-trivial case:

```
vals = [1, 2, 10, 1, 6]
mean = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
diff = [-3, -2, 6, -3, 2]
```

You can identify the moves in any order; for simplicity, we'll go right to left in both groups.  Yes, there is an easy solution if E gives its 2 excess to B, while C supplies 3 each to A and D, but the problem doesn't call for fewest shipments, just efficient number of items moved.

**A** has 1 item, but needs 4: take them from **C**, the first element with an excess, which has 6 extra.

```
vals = [4, 2, 7, 1, 6]
mean = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
diff = [0 -2, 3, -3, 2]
```

**B** needs 2 more items, which it can also get from **C**:

```
vals = [4, 4, 5, 1, 6]
mean = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
diff = [0, 0, 1, -3, 2]
```

**D** needs 3 more, but **C** has only one remaining: take it.

```
vals = [4, 4, 4, 2, 6]
mean = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
diff = [0, 0, 0, -2, 2]
```

... and finally, the last transfer is now obvious.

Does *that* get you moving again?

Comment: Thanks, these seems like a sensible approach. It's a better way to think through the problem than what I was doing.

Comment: Comparing lists to figure out what needs to be moved where does not appear to be trivial. From a mathematical sense, it's easy. But to add context to it so that 1 item is not moving from a to b to c to d and such seems to be rather complex. Taking away from one and distributing to the others is the simple way to describe the problem, but I suppose that's because we can look at all 4 variables at the same time and inherently know the most efficient way to balance things as humans.

Comment: There is no *inherently know* in the process.  analyze how you would do it, as a human: break down the steps.  As a human, why would you move an item from a to b to c to d?  What algorithm are you considering that would cause the program to make that inefficient solution?

Comment: As others have said above, *you* need to take the lead on analysing the problem and working toward a solution.  Your comment suggests that you see a potential problem -- but you have posted no algorithm that has that problem, nor have you given any other approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start.

To get balanced values, you can distribute the average to each variable. There will be some rest ( sum modulo len), just distribute it to the first variables :

```
def distribute(*values):
    low = min(values)
    high = max(values)
    if high - low <= 1:
        print 'already balanced'
        return list(values)
    s = sum(values)
    n = len(values)
    avg = s // n
    result = [avg] * n
    for i in range(s % n):
        result[i] += 1
    return result

print(distribute(1, 2, 0, 0))
# [1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Now you just need the logic to tell how many values should go from one variable to another (e.g. "Move 1 from b to c").