# In python, how do you print a list of steps to transform a list of integers into a provided second list of integers?

Tags: python, list, set, transform

Given This Input:

```
[2,2,2,1], [4,3,0,0]
```

Output:
Steps to transform list

```
Move 2 from C_to_A
Move 1 from D_to_B
```

The lists could be referenced in this manner for ease:

```
[A, B, C, D] #Just some means to reference the to and from of the move.
```

What I have so far:

```
    locations = {
        0: "A",
        1: "B",
        2: "C",
        3: "D"
    }

def get_steps_for_distribution(c, d):
    print 'current: {} desired: {}'.format(c, d)
    for i in range(0, len(c)):
        diff = c[i] - d[i]        
        while diff > 0:
            for j in range(1, len(c)):
                next_index = (i + j) % len(c)
                importer_diff = c[next_index] - d[next_index]
                if importer_diff < 0:
                    number_to_move = min(diff, (0 - importer_diff))
                    diff -= number_to_move
                    importer_diff += number_to_move
                    c[i] -= number_to_move
                    d[i] += number_to_move
                    print_move_line(number_to_move, i, next_index)
```

One problem, for example, is given this set:

```
get_steps([2,2,2,1], [4,3,0,0])
```

Currently it provides steps to shift everything to location A, resulting in this, which is not an accurate representation of the second list provided.:

```
>>>Move 2 from C_to_A
>>>Move 0 from C_to_B
>>>Move 1 from D_to_A
>>>Move 0 from D_to_B
```

Comment: What do you mean by print steps? You can do `print( "my step1, data1 = " + str( data1 ) )`

Comment: Yes, simply printing the steps would be sufficient. It would be a set of instructions like "Move 1 from A to B, Move 2 from D to C" etc.

Comment: wasnt the answers from your last question helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868457/how-do-you-distribute-a-list-of-integers-to-be-as-close-to-balanced-as-possible

Comment: So, you have to write it down, verbosely. Example: `print( "Move 1 from A to B" )`, before the instruction which does `B = A`

Comment: It's currently printing those lines using the print_move_line() function, but it's not performing the move steps correctly. The instructions to match the second input list are incorrect for some cases like the one used in the example.

Comment: @abccd That question got me to this point yes. I don't need a function to equally distribute the integers (I can provide that if needed, but it's not really relevant here. I'm having difficulty figuring out why some examples not behaving as expected with the get_steps() function.

Comment: @user: Kenny has made a good stab at implementing the algorithm I outlined in the previous question.  He has a flaw in one detail, and is asking for help.  In the case he gives, the step "Move 1 from D to A" should, instead, move that unit to B, not A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.  The problem is that you don't update the master list of needs (c) and resource (d).  In the bottom of your code, add a couple of lines to effect those updates:

```
               diff -= number_to_move
               importer_diff += number_to_move
               c[i] -= number_to_move
               d[i] += number_to_move
```

This gradually updates the resource list until it's equal to the needs list.

---

Note: there are a number of things you can improve, once you get this working:

- Variable names: make them more descriptive, and correspond nicely between "export" and "import", as well as within each group.
- Simplify your **next_index** computation with modulus:

  next_index = (i + j) % len(c)
- You don't need to update **importer_diff**; you recompute it on the next loop, anyway.

---

MY SOLUTION

This produces the desired output:

```
locations = {
    0: "A",
    1: "B",
    2: "C",
    3: "D"
}

def print_move_line(number_to_move, exporter, importer):
    line = "Move " + str(number_to_move) + " from " + locations.get(exporter, "bad location") + "_to_" + locations.get(importer, "bad location")
    print line


def get_steps(have, want):
    for exporter_index in range(0, len(have)):
        diff = have[exporter_index] - want[exporter_index]

        # Move 'diff' units from bin 'exporter_index' to others;
        #   offer valid only while supplies last.
        while diff > 0:
            for j in range(1, len(have)):
                # Start next to the exporter and wrap around.
                importer_index = (exporter_index + j) % len(have)
                print("  DEBUG: have", have, "want", want, "\t", exporter_index, "to", importer_index)
                importer_diff = have[importer_index] - want[importer_index]

                # If this bin needs units, move what we have.
                if importer_diff < 0:
                    number_to_move = min(diff, (-importer_diff))
                    print("  DEBUG: bin", importer_index, "needs", importer_diff, "donor has", diff)
                    diff -= number_to_move
                    have[exporter_index] -= number_to_move
                    importer_diff -= number_to_move
                    have[importer_index] += number_to_move
                    print_move_line(number_to_move, exporter_index, importer_index)

get_steps([2, 2, 2, 1], [4, 3, 0, 0])
```

Output:

```
('  DEBUG: have', [2, 2, 2, 1], 'want', [4, 3, 0, 0], '\t', 2, 'to', 3)
('  DEBUG: have', [2, 2, 2, 1], 'want', [4, 3, 0, 0], '\t', 2, 'to', 0)
('  DEBUG: bin', 0, 'needs', -2, 'donor has', 2)
Move 2 from C_to_A
('  DEBUG: have', [2, 2, 4, 1], 'want', [2, 3, 0, 0], '\t', 2, 'to', 1)
('  DEBUG: bin', 1, 'needs', -1, 'donor has', 0)
Move 0 from C_to_B
('  DEBUG: have', [2, 2, 4, 1], 'want', [2, 3, 0, 0], '\t', 3, 'to', 0)
('  DEBUG: have', [2, 2, 4, 1], 'want', [2, 3, 0, 0], '\t', 3, 'to', 1)
('  DEBUG: bin', 1, 'needs', -1, 'donor has', 1)
Move 1 from D_to_B
('  DEBUG: have', [2, 2, 4, 2], 'want', [2, 2, 0, 0], '\t', 3, 'to', 2)
[wdwickar@wdwickar-ws pyside]$ python so.py
('  DEBUG: have', [2, 2, 2, 1], 'want', [4, 3, 0, 0], '\t', 2, 'to', 3)
('  DEBUG: have', [2, 2, 2, 1], 'want', [4, 3, 0, 0], '\t', 2, 'to', 0)
('  DEBUG: bin', 0, 'needs', -2, 'donor has', 2)
Move 2 from C_to_A
('  DEBUG: have', [4, 2, 0, 1], 'want', [4, 3, 0, 0], '\t', 2, 'to', 1)
('  DEBUG: bin', 1, 'needs', -1, 'donor has', 0)
Move 0 from C_to_B
('  DEBUG: have', [4, 2, 0, 1], 'want', [4, 3, 0, 0], '\t', 3, 'to', 0)
('  DEBUG: have', [4, 2, 0, 1], 'want', [4, 3, 0, 0], '\t', 3, 'to', 1)
('  DEBUG: bin', 1, 'needs', -1, 'donor has', 1)
Move 1 from D_to_B
('  DEBUG: have', [4, 3, 0, 0], 'want', [4, 3, 0, 0], '\t', 3, 'to', 2)
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and merged them into the question, to the degree I understood your response. Oddly, though, it's still distributing them incorrectly. It's adding an extra item to A, for a total of [5, 3, 0, 0]; (2 from C to A, and 1 from D to A). This is in reference to the problem set of: current: [2, 2, 2, 1] desired: [4, 3, 0, 0].

Comment: Thanks! I like the debug break down, that's really helpful. Hopefully this helps someone in the future. Also, +1 for the comments humor. :-)